# Generating a random, non-prime number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, primes

How would I generate a non-prime random number in a range in Python?

I am confused as to how I can create an algorithm that would produce a non-prime number in a certain range. Do I define a function or create a conditional statement? I would like each number in the range to have the same probability. For example, in 1 - 100, each non-prime would not have a 1% chance but instead has a ~1.35% chance.

Comment: IsPrime() is not trivial..

Comment: Do you need each non-prime number in the given range to have the same probability?

Comment: @RoryDaulton's question is very important. E.g., you could pick a random number in the bottom half of the range and double it. :-)

Comment: Two basic approaches come to mind: 1) pick a random number, test whether it's prime, and repeat the process if it is; 2) find all the prime numbers in the given range, remove them, and pick one of the remaining numbers at random. Which approach is faster depends on the range and how many times you'll be repeating this process.

Comment: Pick any number, prime or not, in half the range and then double it.  You only need to check that you didn't pick 1 and double it to 2.  This will not give you a truly random selection of non-primes in the range, but it will be very fast.  You could do the same with one third of the range and multiply by 3, checking for 3.

Comment: @rossum (and smarx) If you're going down this path, then just clear the least significant bit of the number you picked to make it even: `n = n & ~1`. You don't need to double it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now, you didn't say anything about efficiency, and this could surely be optimized, but this should solve the problem. This should be an efficient algorithm for testing primality:

```
import random

def isPrime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False

    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))

def randomNonPrime(rangeMin, rangeMax):
    nonPrimes = filter(lambda n: not isPrime(n), xrange(rangeMin, rangeMax+1))
    if not nonPrimes:
        return None

    return random.choice(nonPrimes)

minMax = (1000, 10000)
print randomNonPrime(*minMax)
```

After returning a list of all non-primes in range, a random value is selected from the list of non-primes, making the selection of any non-prime in range just as likely as any other non-prime in the range.

**Edit**

Although you didn't ask about efficiency, I was bored, so I figured out a method of doing this that makes a range of `(1000, 10000000)` take a little over 6 seconds on my machine instead of over a minute and a half:

```
import numpy
import sympy

def randomNonPrime(rangeMin, rangeMax):
    primesInRange = numpy.fromiter(
        sympy.sieve.primerange(rangeMin, rangeMax),
        dtype=numpy.uint32,
        count=-1
    )

    numbersInRange = numpy.arange(rangeMin, rangeMax+1, dtype=numpy.uint32)
    nonPrimes = numbersInRange[numpy.invert(numpy.in1d(numbersInRange, primesInRange))]

    if not nonPrimes.size:
        return None

    return numpy.random.choice(nonPrimes)

minMax = (1000, 10000000)

print randomNonPrime(*minMax)
```

This uses the [SymPy symbolic mathematics library](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to optimize the generation of prime numbers in a range, and then uses [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) to filter our output and select a random non-prime.

Comment: What do you mean by ```isPrime() uses the AKS primality test```?. This surely is not the AKS-test implemented!

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm and ideas to choose is very dependent on your exact use-case, as mentioned by @smarx.

#### Assumptions:

- Each non-prime within the range has the same probability of beeing chosen / **uniformity**
- It is sufficient that the sampled number is not a prime with a **very high probability** (algorithmic false positives are less likely than CPU-bugs & co.)
- The sampling-range could be big (sieve-like approaches are slow)
- High performance of a single sample is desired (no caching; no sampling without replacement)

#### Method:

- Sample random-number in range
- Check if this number is prime with a very fast **probabilistic primality test**
- Stop when observing first non-prime number
- If no number is found, stop algorithm after `max_trials`
- `max_trials`-value is set by an approximation to the Coupon-Collectors-Problem ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)): expected number of samples to observe each candidate once

#### Characteristics of method

- Fast for single samples (**10000 samples per second on single CPU**; given range as in example)
- Easy to prove uniformity
- Good asymptotic behaviour regarding range-size and range-position (number sizes)

#### Code

```python
    import random
    import math

    """ Miller-Rabin primality test
            source: https://jeremykun.com/2013/06/16/miller-rabin-primality-test/
    """

    def decompose(n):
       exponentOfTwo = 0

       while n % 2 == 0:
          n = n//2  # modified for python 3!
          exponentOfTwo += 1

       return exponentOfTwo, n

    def isWitness(possibleWitness, p, exponent, remainder):
       possibleWitness = pow(possibleWitness, remainder, p)

       if possibleWitness == 1 or possibleWitness == p - 1:
          return False

       for _ in range(exponent):
          possibleWitness = pow(possibleWitness, 2, p)

          if possibleWitness == p - 1:
             return False

       return True

    def probablyPrime(p, accuracy=100):
       if p == 2 or p == 3: return True
       if p < 2: return False

       exponent, remainder = decompose(p - 1)

       for _ in range(accuracy):
          possibleWitness = random.randint(2, p - 2)
          if isWitness(possibleWitness, p, exponent, remainder):
             return False

       return True

    """ Coupon-Collector Problem (approximation)
            How many random-samplings with replacement are expected to observe each element at least once
    """
    def couponcollector(n):
        return int(n*math.log(n))

    """ Non-prime random-sampling
    """
    def get_random_nonprime(min, max):
        max_trials = couponcollector(max-min)
        for i in range(max_trials):
            candidate = random.randint(min, max)
            if not probablyPrime(candidate):
                return candidate
        return -1

    # TEST
    print(get_random_nonprime(1000, 10000000))
```